# ant sonar not working

Tags: sonarqube

```
 <target name="sonar">
            <taskdef uri="antlib:org.sonar.ant" resource="org/sonar/ant/antlib.xml">
            </taskdef>

            <sonar:sonar />
    </target>
```

I also have the SONAR_HOME environment variable set but when i execute "ant sonar" i get the following error am i missing something

```
BUILD FAILED
/root/.jenkins/jobs/Project/workspace/dev/archive/build.xml:108: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
The following mandatory information is missing:
- task attribute 'key'
- task attribute 'version'
    at org.sonar.ant.SonarTask.checkMandatoryProperties(SonarTask.java:212)
    at org.sonar.ant.SonarTask.execute(SonarTask.java:190)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:392)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:413)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1399)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1368)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1251)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:811)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:217)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:280)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:109)
```

Total time: 0 seconds

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use the "syntaxt" of the latest version of the Ant task (2.0) but it seems that this is not the version you have in your classpath.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're missing the mandatory SonarQube property values that belong in your build.xml file.

From the [docs](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+Ant)

```
<!-- Define the SonarQube global properties (the most usual way is to pass 
these properties via the command line) -->
<property name="sonar.host.url" value="http://localhost:9000" />

...

<!-- Define the SonarQube project properties -->
<property name="sonar.projectKey" value="org.sonarqube:sonarqube-scanner-ant" />
<property name="sonar.projectName" value="Example of SonarQube Scanner for Ant Usage" />
<property name="sonar.projectVersion" value="1.0" />
<property name="sonar.sources" value="src" />
<property name="sonar.java.binaries" value="build" />
<property name="sonar.java.libraries" value="lib/*.jar" />
```

Alternatively, you could also pass these values into ANT as arguments.

```
ant sonar -Dsonar.projectVersion=1.1
```